# Refreshing header's component on other component's initialization in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, refresh

I'm building a multi page application that's based on Angular on the front. My app.component.html is made of:

```
<app-header></>(header component)
<app-sidenav></> (side navigation component)
and everything else is in <router-outlet></>.
```

In my header component, I have a bookmark button that opens a modal for adding a page to Favorites. It takes an url of a current page that's loaded on users screen and lets a user choose the page's name. The logic I'm trying to implement is next: if that page's url is already in user's favorites (which gets checked by the function from favoritesService, the bookmark button should change it's color and become disabled. This logic works perfect in a way that it compares current url with an array of added url's but the button's color doesn't change and it doesn't become disabled untill I refresh the page( because the function for checking if a page is already a favorite is called on header component's ngOnInit and it loads only at the start of the application(the boolean attribute in the header component doesn't get refreshed otherwise)). So, just a few more sentences to clarify, in case you didn't understand the scenario: Header component is loading at the start; user is browsing other pages not depending on the header component. When I change the page, header should check if the current page is already a favorite and if it is, a button from header.component.html should change its color and become disabled. This works perfectly, but only after I reload the whole browser, because only then is when the header's component gets refreshed and triggers the function for comparing URL's.

Answer (score 0):

here you can do state management by using observable or BehaviorSubject. with that you can update your header component.